# Could sheets of stacked graphene be used as part of a heat shield, since its melting point is 3000k to 5000 K

Tags: reentry, design-alternative, materials, thermal, heat-shield

Since graphene material is the strongest manmade material, with "magical" properties, I wonder if it could be considered for use as a heat shield, since its melting point is 3000 to 5000 K stacked at 10 layers thick, which is higher than reentry temperatures.

Comment: I disagree, since melting is about the least important parameter.  Thermal conductivity and flash point (once a little O2 is available) seem far more interesting.

Comment: For "reentry" you would also need to consider abrasive resistance properties no?

Comment: "Cardboard -- cardboard is out..." (https://youtu.be/3m5qxZm_JqM?t=49)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica *brilliant!* You've opened up a whole new world of videos I can watch to avoid doing what I'm supposed to :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The melting point is of such paramount importance for a classic heat shield that we mentally screen out all materials that melt early before we even spend the first conscious thought on them. It only *seems* unimportant. There is a reason we don't use wax or PE (or water ice, whose flash point is non-existing).

Answer (score 30):

For a non ablative heat shield you need a material with a very high melting point and a very low thermal conductivity. It should not burn in hot air.

Unfortunately graphene seems to have a high thermal conductivity, higher than pyrolytic graphite.  In-plane thermal conductivity could help to avoid hot spots, but through-planes conductivity should be low as commented by @uhoh.

It burns at very low temperature of 350 °C, the reaction with oxygen starts below 260 °C as commented by @GremlinWranger.

Source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphene#Thermal_conductivity

Comment: From the same link we also have the fact at burns in oxygen above 260 degrees.

Comment: For highly anisotropic materials like stacked graphene the in-plane thermal conductivity (what you'd want for heat redistribution and avoiding hot spots) may be much higher than conductivity through the stack; and it may be much harder to find an actual measurement of through-stack conductivity for stacked graphene material proper.

Comment: @uhoh I'd be pretty confident that if you could robustly stack sheets of graphene , the cross-plane TC would be considerably lower than the in-plane.  This would be especially true if there was no periodicity in the stack, as heat transport in graphene is at least partly reliant on phonons.  A high in-plane TC would help conduct heat from the very hottest regions to those that are merely scorching.

Comment: OTOH in a thin layer of material (e.g. a few hundred graphene monolayer), heat flow in plane does some strange things because of phonon confinement

Comment: @Gremlin yes hot oxygen will be its kryptonite!

Comment: @uhoh yes, it is, but rather too thin for this at the moment.  As it grows thicker, to stay graphene-like it would probably have to be a collection of thin stacks (of the type you linked) rather than one thick stack

Comment: Yes, the idea, ultimately, is to *not pot roast the astronauts* - not simply to ensure the structural integrity of the vehicle... hence the "shield" part of "heat shield".

Comment: is _graphit_ different from _graphite_ or is that a typo?

Answer (score 4):

“Sheets of stacked graphene”? Ok: look no further than [graphite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphite), AKA carbon. It very much *is* used for its thermal properties, in applications such as electrodes that can withstand molten aluminium.

And, indeed, heat shields. Specifically, [carbon fibre reinforced carbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforced_carbon%E2%80%93carbon), which is what the Space Shuttle's leading edges were made of.

Now, ok, graphite isn't actually what you would understand by “stacked graphene”. It's only tiny flakes of graphene that are barely coupled together. But for a heat shield, that's actually a good thing, because heat conductance works excellent along the sheet but not so well between the layers. On the other hand, graphite has pretty rubbish mechanical properties because the flakes easily separate from each other, that why you need *reinforced* graphite.

Comment: @uhoh graphite _is_ stacked graphene, it's just too many stacked to display the quirks of the 2D geometry, and too weakly/unorderly coupled to see the mechanical and conductance superpowers. But it's still what it is, and indeed the thermal stability is one of the ways where graphite behaves just like any other arrangement of graphene.

Comment: But stacked graphene is not necessarily graphite. Stacked graphene can be much more. They are not synonymous, a lump of graphite is not representative of all forms of stacked graphene. It's not superconducting for example!  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twistronics and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilayer_graphene

Comment: @uhoh definitely, but the question was not about some particular configuration of graphene, just about “stacked graphene”, of which graphite is an example. In many ways it's a “crippled” and boring example of stacked graphene, but heat shields happen to be an application where it works. — Admittedly my answer was phrased a bit bad as well.